# Aggregate the data of multiple numpy files into one

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list which contains 6 different sub-dataset of a dataset. I would like to perform 6 fold cross-validation. Therefore, in a for-loop of 6 steps each time to split my dataset into 2 groups (training that will contain the 5 sub-datasets and test set - contain the leave one sub-dataset). My code looks like:

**EDIT(by taking into account the comments):**

```
sets = ['datasets/1.pickle', 'datasets/2.pickle', ..., 'datasets/6.pickle']
for i in range(0,7):
  train_set = sets[:i]+sets[i+1:]
  test_data, test_lbls = crossValidFiles(sets[i]) # returns the data for a specific sub-samlpe, returns two numpy arrays.
  for item in train_set:
      train_set = [(train_data, train_lbls) for crossValidFiles(item) in train_set]
      train_data = np.concatenate([a for (a,b) in train_set], axis = 0)
      train_lbls = np.concatenate([b for (a,b) in train_set], axis = 0)
      #train_data, train_lbls = crossValidFiles(item) # that returns one file at time.
```

How can I aggregate the files that I return for the training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.concatenate()`: [np concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
t1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
t2 = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
train array = np.concatenate((t1,t2), axis=0)
```

to process your files I would extract the `train_data` and `train_lbls` for your data, then just concate a list of each. e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
t1 = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), np.array(['train_lbls'])]
t2 = [np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]), np.array(['train_lbls'])]
train_set = [t1,t2]
train_set = [(train_data, train_lbls) for crossValidFiles(item) in train_set]
train_data = np.concatenate([a for (a,b) in train_set], axis=0)
train_lbls = np.concatenate([b for (a,b) in train_set], axis=0)
```

Comment: Can I do that within the for-loop?

Comment: I am receiving the message cant assign to function call for the usage of crossValidFiles.

Comment: Can you edit your code and the error into the question?

Comment: I modified the question!

Comment: Wait, does it work for you now? Or are you still getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to [Mason's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58272174/2740563) answer, you can use np.concatenate inside your crossValidFiles function so that whatever code in there is run on the aggregated test data.

```
import numpy as np

def crossValidFiles(input_file):
    data, labels = some_load_function(input_file)
    return data, labels

def some_load_function(input_file):
    # Check if the input file is a string or list-like
    if isinstance(input_file, str):
        train_array = some_load_function_2(input_file)
    else:
        train_array = np.concatenate([some_load_function_2(f) for f in input_file], axis=0)

    # rest of your code to create variables 'data' and 'labels'
    return data, labels
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960255/2740563).

Comment: My some_load_function returns two numpy arrays of data and labels. Therefore, when I run "train_array = np.concatenate([some_load_function(f) for f in input_file], axis=0)" I am receiving the following error: ValueError: Could not broadvast input array from shape () to shape ().

Comment: In that case, you would put the if-else block inside the some_load_function definition (edited my answer). I left out a lot since I don't know what your functions look like. Mason's answer should work too.