# Appending arrays from different files and insert a column to data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The data in my case are 2D arrays available in multiple files. In the end, I would like to append these 2D arrays row-wise. For example, say fileA contains

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and fileB contains

```
7 8 9
0 1 2
```

I would like the resulting operation to be

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
0 1 2
```

The easiest way to do this is as per the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960195/python-fast-way-to-get-data-from-multiple-files-in-single-numpy-array) something like

```
data = np.concatenate([np.loadtxt(f) for f in filenames])
```

However, I would like to include a column during this operation. For example, let `x = [3, 5]` with length of x = number of files. Each file's row length is fixed (and in this case is 2). I would like the resulting array to be:

```
3 1 2 3
3 4 5 6
5 7 8 9
5 0 1 2
```

How to achieve this in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None).assign(x=x) 
           for (f,x) in zip(filenames, x_list)]
```

You would get the `x` column last. If you insist on having it first, you can try:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in filenames],
          keys=x_list).reset_index(level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! Could you please explain the answer as well, specifically how `keys` and `reset_index` achieve this?

Comment: in short, `keys` option labels the data by the key list as the first level index. Then use `reset_index` to turn that level into a normal column. You can print the `concat(..., keys=..)` out to see.